# How to configure Gcloud Python Pyca library

Tags: python, ubuntu, cryptography, gcloud

I am having trouble importing the key to the Google Cloud KMS. How to get the key imported to gcloud KMS?

Even if latest version of pyca library is installed then still no attribute 'aes_key_wrap_with_padding' is found. When removing pyca from pip and from ubuntu 20.04 then still the gcloud cli is able to find invalid version somewhere.

```
gcloud kms keys versions import   --import-job importing-soft-key-2   --location europe-north1   --keyring eID-Easy-ring-1   --key Soft   --algorithm rsa-sign-pkcs1-2048-sha256 --target-key-file mykey.key
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): module 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap' has no attribute 'aes_key_wrap_with_padding'
```

Comment: Similar error was appearing when old Pyca version was installed. Which version you have? Are you sure it's latest?

Comment: There is no Pyca installed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install Pyca cryptography library. In Google Documentation in Importing key section there is [article](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/crypto) about it:

> update the gcloud command-line tool to enable support for automatically wrapping keys for secure import into Cloud Key Management Service, by installing the Pyca cryptography library. Version 2.2.0 or higher adds support for the required aes_key_wrap_with_padding wrapping mechanism.

I think the documentation explains how to do it well enough for many OS.

Comment: Tried on multiple machines. Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04. Using PIP and apt-get. Nothing worked. Finally used Windows to get it done